# Setting local notification for current date and time is not working using Swift 3

Tags: ios, date, swift3, unusernotificationcenter

I am new in local notification and I have to implement a task. I have a reminder date and text so I want to show local notification according to reminderDate and current date.

1. If reminder date is 7 days before to current date then I have to show notification
2. If reminder date is 2 days before to current date then I have to show reminders.
3. On the same day in evening 5 PM I have to show reminder text.

My sample code is:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //getNotificationSettings()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}

//Button Alarm
@IBAction func btnAlarm(_ sender: Any) {

    let date = Date()

    /*let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"

    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    let originalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    //let dateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(Date())*/

    scheduleNotification(at: date!)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "answer1" {
        print("Answer 1")
    }

    else if response.actionIdentifier == "textNotification" {
        print("Answer Text Notification")
    }

    completionHandler()
}


//Schedule Notification
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Tutorial Reminder"
    content.body = "Just a reminder to read your tutorial over at appcoda.com!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "logo", url: url, options: nil)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        } catch {
            print("The attachment was not loaded.")
        }
    }

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have check the permission in Appdelegate.swift file :-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     //getNotificationSettings()
    registerForPushNotifications()
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    //self.saveContext()
}

/*func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    }
}*/

/*func getNotificationSettings() {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}*/

func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that above task and why local notification is not showing for current date in my code is local time or anything else?

Comment: You need to schedule 3 different local notification. 1) 7 day before 2) 2 day before  3) Same day at scheduled time

Comment: Yes Surjeet I have to do the same.

Comment: I tried too. But no luck. Please use deprecated framework UILocalNotification and use repeatInterval property.

Comment: UILocalNotification is deprecated I guess in iOS 10.

Comment: @kishor0011 I guess you able to schedule single notification and just having trouble to schedule multiple notification according to your requirement?

Comment: No Actually that single notification is not able to schedule. Once that will schedule then I will switch to my task Thanks

Comment: I guess that current date is giving problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, instead of using current date, add few minutes in current time and then schedule notification. It will work.

Comment: Is there anything that for particular time in evening I can schedule it? Thanks

Comment: As mentioned in your question, if you want to schedule at 5 Pm, Use this  let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: 17, minute: 0)

Comment: Oh Okay and Like this I can schedule for 7 days and 2 days before?

Comment: How can I schedule it for multiple Reminders? Please Help.
Because I am using for loop and Its showing for one only. Thanks